# Ionic 5 SSR local development not reloading on CSS, SCSS changes

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, webpack, ionic5

Running local development with `ng run app:serve-ssr`

It's an Ionic 5 project

```
"@angular/cli": "~11.0.5",
"@ionic/angular-server": "5.6.0-dev.202012021910.3a763f4",
"@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.3.0",
```

Reload works fine, except on `.scss` file changes.

Maybe somebody had a similar issue or knows how to locate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding `/styles/styles.scss` and adding `@import 'src/app/app.component.scss';` to it, it started working again.

Also added

```
{
   "input": "src/styles/styles.scss"
}
```

to `styles` in `angular.json`